# XMLDocument load xml with Http line break "&#13"

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am working on a SOAP flow in which I get a saml Assertion including its signature and digest value from back and need to include it into the next call.

Call 1 returns saml Assertion including Signature and digest
Return must be inserted and signed in Call 2

I thought this should be pretty basic. However, the return from Call 1 looks like the following:

```
   AwwNQWVTLUktQ0EtVGVzdDEWMBQGA1UECgwNQWdlbmNlIGVTYW50ZTELMAkGA1UE&#13;
   BhMCTFUwHhcNMjMwOTE4MTU1OTU1WhcNMjUwOTE3MTU1OTU0WjCBqTEqMCgGCSqG&#13;
   SIb3DQEJARYbZnJhbmsuc2NocmVpbmVyNjhAeWFob28uY29tMR4wHAYDVQQDDBVE&#13;
```

as you can see there is a '
' an html carriage return.

Now I insert this as string into my new xml string. Afterwards I load the string to xml:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Format the document to ignore white spaces.
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
...
doc.LoadXml(template);
doc = Utils.sign(doc);
```

Afterwards I sign the XML and convert it via the code below to string to post it.

```
  StringWriterUTF8 stringWriter = new StringWriterUTF8();
  String xmlString = "";
  using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                xmlString = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }

   public class StringWriterUTF8 : StringWriter
        {
            public override Encoding Encoding
            {
                get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
            }
        }
```

However, the xml looks like this:

```
AwwNQWVTLUktQ0EtVGVzdDEWMBQGA1UECgwNQWdlbmNlIGVTYW50ZTELMAkGA1UE
BhMCTFUwHhcNMjMwOTE4MTU1OTU1WhcNMjUwOTE3MTU1OTU0WjCBqTEqMCgGCSqG
SIb3DQEJARYbZnJhbmsuc2NocmVpbmVyNjhAeWFob28uY29tMR4wHAYDVQQDDBVE
```

and the digest value of the assertion is wrong leading to a bad request...

Can anybody help me out?

thank you!

Comment: Your code looks really strange , what the sence of it?  why you just dont use  xmlString=template

Comment: Ah sorry, i should have posted a bit more code. As I need to sign the XML I need to load the string into an xml object, sign it and revert it to string.